# $N(\alpha) = \pm 1 \implies \alpha$ is invertible - Is my proof correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] = \{a + b\sqrt{2}\mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Let $N(a + b\sqrt{2}) = a^2 - 2b^2$

Let $N(\alpha\beta) = N(\alpha)N(\beta)$ for $\alpha, \ \beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$

**Claim:** $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is invertible if and only if $N(\alpha) = \pm 1$

I would like some feedback on my proof of the second part of this statement to make sure I am correct. I.e. if $N(\alpha) = \pm 1 \implies \alpha$ is invertible.

Suppose $\alpha\beta \neq 1$ for any $\beta$. I.e. $\alpha$ is not invertible.

Then we have that

$N(\alpha\beta) \neq N(1)$

$N(\alpha)N(\beta) \neq N(1)$

Assuming that $N(\alpha) = \pm 1$ gives that

$\pm N(\beta) = 1$

If we take $\beta$ to be $1$ or $-1$ this equality is satisfied. Hence we have contradiction. Therefore $\alpha$ is invertible.

Does that seem ok?

Comment: Would it be easier to argue that if $N(\alpha)=\pm 1$, then $(a-b\sqrt{2})(a+b\sqrt{2})=\pm 1$, so that $\pm(a-b\sqrt{2})$ is the inverse of $a+b\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: When you wrote $N(\alpha\beta)\neq N(1)$ for all $\beta$, you didn't really justify that. Indeed, $N$ is not injective.
I would suggest you look at $(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: To see why your assumption that $N(\alpha \beta) \neq N(1)$ is wrong, consider $3 + 2\sqrt{2}$. $N(3 + 2\sqrt{2}) = 1 = N(1)$ but $3 + 2\sqrt{2}$ is certainly not $1$.

Comment: Should have spotted that I couldn't treat $\neq$ like $=$, time for a break!

Comment: @OldJohn That's a nice way of doing it cheers.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more conceptual proof, which only uses that $\alpha$ is integral (which is true since
$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is integrally closed), and the definition of the norm. So there is the characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$, say, $x^n+\cdots +a_0$, so that
$$
\alpha^n+\cdots +a_1\alpha+a_0=0
$$
and $a_0=\pm N(\alpha)=\pm 1$, because the constant term here is the norm up to sign. This just means
$$
\pm \alpha (\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1)=1,
$$
so that $\alpha$ is invertible.